# Symfony2 Exception on web/web_dev.php

Tags: php, symfony

Following the Symfony2 guide it says to view `web/web_dev.php` but I get a exception..
The `app/check.php` is all fine except one optional test fails:

```
[[WARNING]] Checking that the intl ICU version is at least 4+: FAILED
            *** Upgrade your intl extension with a newer ICU version (4+) ***
```

This is the exception:

```
RuntimeException: Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/projectname/www/Symfony/app/cache)
in /var/www/projectname/www/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 1197
at Kernel->buildContainer() in /var/www/projectname/www/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 1138
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in /var/www/projectname/www/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 869
at Kernel->boot() in /var/www/projectname/www/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 1038
at Kernel->loadClassCache() in /var/www/projectname/www/Symfony/web/app_dev.php line 12
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who gives me light on how to solve this

Comment: Creating a `app/cache` directory with sufficient permissions (eg. 0777) should be enough.

Answer (score 9):

The error message is quite clear: it is unable to create the cache directory - the user apache runs as has no write permission for your project root.

Assuming it's a development environment, I recomment chowning the project folder to your user and the webserver's group.

Answer (score 6):

just for people's info.
I had the same issue when working locally on a mac and had to change the permissions on two directories:
app/cache
app/logs

'Command i' on each directory and set the permissions to 'Read & Write' for everyone (and applied to Enclosed Items) did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to "Setting up Permissions" in Symfony2 documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

1. Using ACL on a system that supports chmod +a
   CODE: SELECT ALL
   sudo chmod +a "apache allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs

Results in:
chmod: invalid mode: `+a'

1. Using Acl on a system that does not support chmod +a
   CODE: SELECT ALL
   sudo setfacl -R -m u:apache:rwx -m u:myname:rwx app/cache app/logs

Results in:
sudo: setfacl: command not found

1. Without using ACL
   Uncommenting "//umask(0000);"